# Emacs: move any "//" pattern to specific column

Tags: emacs, cursor, comments, indentation

I used to start all my comments from column 60.

Is there a trick in Emacs with which for the current line, anything after (and including) `//`  is pushed to column 60?

**Example**

```
cmp A, B // comparing against a reference
```

becomes

```
cmp A, B <-- extra spaces added until column 60 ---> // comparing against a reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `comment-column` to 60, and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd>.

Note that <kbd>M-;</kbd> runs `comment-dwim` which tries to do what you mean.  Notably, if the region is active, it will comment out the entire region.  If this gets in your way, the command that does what you ask for above is `comment-indent`, which you could bind to a suitable key.

Comment: Is there a limitation about the number of characters in the comment ? I noticed that the M-; doesn't work for long sentences.

Comment: I found the solution : Fill column set to 120 (was 70)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `comment-column` as said by legoscia, select a region and call `M-x align-regexp RET // RET`. That will align your comments on the same column.

For the doc: `C-h f align-regexp`.